# I have to unwrap optional twice in switch statement inside didSet

Tags: swift, option-type, swift5

```
var test: Int! {
    didSet {
        switch test {
        case 1: print("one")
        case 2: print("two")
        default: print("something else")
        }
    }
}

var toupleTest: (one: Int, two: Int)! {
    didSet {
        switch toupleTest! {
        case (1, 1): print("one, one")
        case (2, 2): print("two, two")
        default: print("something else")
        }
    }
}

test = 2 // prints "two"
toupleTest = (1, 1) // prints "one, one"
```

In a case of Int value everything is ok.
But in a case of tuple I have to unwrap the optional twice! Otherwise I've got a compile error.
Looks like swift logic is inconsistent. Or is it a bug?

Comment: That's because the type of the property (Int, Int)? doesn't match the type you use in the switch case's which are (Int,Int)

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Then why it works as expected in the first example? In the first example type of the property Int? doesn't match the type I use in the switch case's which are Int.

Comment: I think its because Int is a named (predefined) type while the tuple is a compound type so the compiler somehow knows how to match 1 to Int? but not how to match a more dynamic type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is inconsistent, but the reason is a bit complex.

In order for a type to be used in a `switch` statement, it needs to conform to `Equatable`.

Look at this example using a new `struct` type:

```
struct MyType: Equatable {
    let x: Int
    
    static func ==(lhs: MyType, rhs: MyType) -> Bool {
        return lhs.x == rhs.x
    }
}

var mytypeTest: MyType! {
    didSet {
        switch mytypeTest {
        case MyType(x: 1): print("one")
        case MyType(x: 2): print("two")
        default: print("something else")
        }
    }
}

mytypeTest = MyType(x: 1)
```

This works, but if you remove `: Equatable` from `MyType` you will get the error **Operator function '~=` requires that 'MyType' conform to 'Equatable'**.

So there's the first hint.  `switch` uses the `~=` operator for comparisons and the type must be `Equatable`.

So what happens if we try to compare two tuples using '~=':

```
if (1, 3) ~= (1, 3) {
    print("same")
}
```

This gives the error: **Type '(Int, Int)' cannot conform to 'Equatable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols**.

So, this would imply that tuples can't be used in a `switch` and we know that isn't true.

Well, tuples have a special place in a `switch`, and they're used in *pattern matching* for deconstructing the tuple.  For example:

```
let a = (1, 2)

switch a {
case let (x, y):
    print("the tuple values are \(x) and \(y)")
}
```

This prints `the tuple values are 1 and 2`.

So, tuples are used in `switch` for matching and deconstructing using *pattern matching*.  So you can use a tuple in a `switch` even though it doesn't conform to `Equatable` because it has this special use.

The problem with your example is that the pattern doesn't match the type you are switching on.  The type of your value is `(Int, Int)?` and the pattern is `(Int, Int)`.

So, how can you fix this without force unwrapping the tuple value?  Change your pattern to match by adding `?` to the pattern:

```
var toupleTest: (one: Int, two: Int)! {
    didSet {
        switch toupleTest {
        case (1, 1)?: print("one, one")
        case (2, 2)?: print("two, two")
        default: print("something else")
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Adding `?` works for your `Int` example as well:

```
var test: Int! {
    didSet {
        switch test {
        case 1?: print("one")
        case 2?: print("two")
        default: print("something else")
        }
    }
}
```

but it isn't necessary because `Int` is `Equatable` and Swift knows how to compare an `Int?` to an `Int` for equality.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's happened because tuples is value type in swift. And default types also default types as well. Basically your unwrap do nothing, you just mark that this value will be non optional. But to access values inside you have to unwrap your optional tuple and reach values